# Event.target в JS

Tags: javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в работе event:

```
function logEvent(event) {
   console.log(event)
   console.log(event.target)
}

<h1 onclick="logEvent()">Click<h1>
```

Почему здесь в первом логе выводит undefined, а во втором - TypeError: 'target' is not a function ?

Comment: Потому что онклик ожидает калбек, а вы передали результат вызова функции logEvent. Какой может быть event у undefined?

Comment: Подскажите как исправить, чтобы при онклик я мог манипулировать event?

Comment: Полезно будет почитать, там объяснены многие трудные моменты, в том числе ваш случай: https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам необходимо передать параметр в функцию, под названием `event`.

```js
function logEvent(e) {
  console.log(e.target)
}
```

```html
<h1 onclick="logEvent(event)">Click</h1>
```

Лучше навешивать слушатели в js файле, дабы не искать потом в огромном html файле, где там происходит `onclick`.

Как пример:

```js
const clickable = document.querySelector('.clickable') // если несколько элементов, то используйте querySelectorAll

function logEvent (e) {
  console.log(e.target)
}

clickable.addEventListener('click', logEvent) // 1 вариант
clickable.addEventListener('click', e => logEvent(e)) // 2 вариант (читайте про стрелочные функции и их отличия от обычных
clickable.onclick = logEvent // 3 вариант, тоже можно, но лучше так не делать :)
```

```html
<h1 class="clickable">Click</h1>
```

Comment: Спасибо! понятно теперь